# Manage with limit and offset in php

Tags: php, limit, offset, musicbrainz

I am currently developing a web application that will find artists and their associates titles. To do this, I decided to parse the API MusicBrainz, through [this package](https://packagist.org/packages/mikealmond/musicbrainz) (which documentation is [here](https://github.com/mikealmond/musicbrainz)).

Suppose I already have the artist mbid (unique identifier for MusicBrainz).

The problem is that if I do a search on David Guetta (`mbid = 302bd7b9-d012-4360-897a-93b00c855680`) for example, the script tells me that the number of releases is 196. However, the API provides 100 maximum results per request.

```
// Instantiate a MusicBrainz object
$brainz = new MusicBrainz(new GuzzleHttpAdapter(new Client()));
$brainz->setUserAgent('ApplicationName', '0.2', 'http://example.com');

$limit = 100;
$offset = 0;

$includes = array('labels', 'recordings');
try {
  $details = $brainz->browseRelease('artist', '302bd7b9-d012-4360-897a-93b00c855680', $includes, $limit, $offset);
  print_r($details);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  print $e->getMessage();
}
```

The function **`browseRelease`** below allows us to define such parameters as **`limit`** and **`offset`**.

```
public function browseRelease($entity, $mbid, $includes = array(), $limit = 25, $offset = null, $releaseType = array(), $releaseStatus = array())
{
  if (!in_array($entity, array('artist', 'label', 'recording', 'release-group'))) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid browse entity for release');
  }
  return $this->browse(
    new Filters\ReleaseFilter(array()),
      $entity,
      $mbid,
      $includes,
      $limit,
      $offset,
      $releaseType,
      $releaseStatus
  );
}
```

Now we come to my real question in this post.

If I defined `$limit = 100` and `$offset = 0` for the first query, I don't understand how to change these values depending on the number of total releases, and thus get the results that are between 100 and 196 (in this example).

Comment: I dont know php but dont you just set $offset=100 in the first query to get the next set of records

Comment: say you have 150 results. First call you do: `$offset = 0`. Then you call again with `$offset = 100`. The limit doesn't matter: if the limit is 100, but there are only 50 results available, it will give you 50 results, starting from the offset value.

Comment: Maybe mark his answer as accepted? That's the way to say "thank you" on SO when someone helps you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo code answer from [Jordumus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662331/1904815) is correct, but this is how you have to modify your code to make it work.

```
$limit = 100;
$offset = 0;
$release_count = 0;

$includes = array('labels', 'recordings');
do {
  if ($offset != 0) sleep(1);
  try {
    $details = $brainz->browseRelease('artist', '302bd7b9-d012-4360-897a-93b00c855680', $includes, $limit, $offset);
    $release_count = $details['release-count'];
    print_r($details);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
  }
  $offset += $limit;
} while ($offset < $release_count);
```

Note that it would be enough to set `$release_count` the first time, since the value doesn't change, but resetting it also doesn't hurt.

I added a `sleep` in there because of the required [rate limiting](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2#Limiting_Connections_to_the_MusicBrainz_Web_Service) which doesn't seem to be implemented in the PHP library.

Comment: Wow, that's working !!!!! I have edited your post, because print_r returned error 502 bad gateway. I have put var_dump instead. Thank you very much !

Comment: The 502 has nothing to do with `print_r`/`var_dump` since the 502 error/exception is thrown on `browseRelease()`. The musicbrainz server has these kinds of hiccups from time to time. For this reason you should have some (manual or automatic) "retry" mechanism when errors like that come up.

Comment: Indeed, after several tests, I have seen that mb server didn't work and then it work without  any changes. Yes. I will put exceptions to see which request doesn't work. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

As of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment), I'll post my answer as a "real answer":

**Pseudolanguage**

Given: 150 results.
You can define: offset and limit.
But: max limit is 100 results.

You'll need 2 calls, because you can only get 100 results at a time. This is how you could solve it:

Call 1:

```
Offset: 0
Limit: 100
//Returns results 0 to 99.
```

Call 2:

```
Offset: 100
Limit: [OPTIONAL] 100
//Returns resuls 100 to 199. As there are only 150 results in total, it will automatically return 100 to 150
```

Now, we could also make this automatic with a loop:

```
limit = 100
for (var i = 0; i < maxResults; i=i+100)
{
    offset = i
    GetResults(offset,limit);
}
```

Comment: Don't understand why it returns an array of size = 25 and then an array of size = 96 ... What's the problem ? (Default limit value = 25, but why it is doing that ?)